# How to remove alternate justification in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tex

I got some big latex source that compiles to a booklet that justifies text in an alternating manner, left-right-left-right, so that it's nice for printing I guess. How can you remove that? I can't share the entire thing, but it starts with:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    outer=2cm,
    inner=4cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
%\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{dkred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0.0}

\lstdefinestyle{DOS}
{
    backgroundcolor=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{white}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{white},
    keywords={}
}

\lstdefinestyle{makefile}
{
    numberblanklines=false,
    language=make,
    tabsize=4,
    keywordstyle=\color{red},
    identifierstyle= %plain identifiers for make
}
```

Comment: Without having a [mre] that reproduces the issue, it is hard to try to help you.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz found the answer actually, shortly after I posted this, bah!

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer, and it was because of some code that I didn't include above

````
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\small \rightmark}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE]{\small \thepage}```

It was the LO, RE that means Left side when odd page, right side on even pages. So, changed that to LO, LE and it's now consistent
````